# How to use arrays to access files in folder in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

had some troubles with this code. It actually is intended to allocate values to the dir1array(ctr1) and dir2array(ctr2) by looping thru all the files in the directory/folder; Is there a way to make this array work ?

```
Option Explicit

'*********************************************************************
'* Verify if files have the same name before proceeding to compare   *
'* their  length                                                     *
'*                     DYNAMIC ARRAYs                                *
'*********************************************************************

Sub findMatchFilenames()

    'Dim fso As fileSystemObject
    Dim objMapinfo
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim dir1 As Folder
    Dim dir2 As Folder
    Dim file1 As File
    Dim file2 As File
    Dim dir1array() As String
    Dim dir2array() As String
    ReDim dir1array(0 To 100) As String
    ReDim dir2array(0 To 100) As String
    Dim ctr1 As Integer
    Dim ctr2 As Integer
    Dim lLen1 As Long, lLen2 As Long
    Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set dir1 = fso.GetFolder("c:\Temp\")
    Set dir2 = fso.GetFolder("c:\Tempo\")


    ctr1 = 0
    For Each file1 In dir1.Files
      ctr2 = 0
      For Each file2 In dir2.Files

       dir1array(ctr1) = file1.Name
       dir2array(ctr2) = file2.Name
       If dir1array(ctr1) = dir2array(ctr2) Then
            MsgBox "" & dir1array(ctr1) & "" & dir2array(ctr2)
            Debug.Print file1.Name & " matches " & file2.Name
            lLen1 = FileLen(file1)
            lLen2 = FileLen(file2)
                If lLen1 <> lLen2 Then
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                MsgBox "The files have the same length"               
            End If
        End If

      ctr2 = ctr2 + 1
     Next file2
      ctr1 = ctr1 + 1

     Next file1

    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I have had some troubles with this code. It actually is intended to allocate values to the dir1array(ctr1) and dir2array(ctr2) by looping thru all the files in the directory/folder; Is there a way to make this array work ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add 'Option Explicit' at the top of your module and Compile... you are missing an 'End If' a couple 'Next' ... maybe more... Fix & repost your code..

Comment: I reposted the whole code now. As you can see I also have a similar issue with the bytArr1(lCtr) and byArr2(lCtr) array at the end of the code.

Comment: Not sure how many files you have in each of the two folders, but my test bombs because you have 'ReDim' to 20 and I have more than 20 files. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code? It drives me crazy with all the message boxes -- maybe you are just debugging, but I would use 'Debug.Print' instead.

Comment: I see your problem - your code is comparing using vbTextCompare, then you have 'If vbBinaryCompare = 0 Then' which will always result in a TRUE condition because you are testing a constant of 0 against 0 (yes, vbCompareBinary is a constant of 0). But since I don't know what you want to if results <> or = ... I can't offer a solution...

Comment: Thank you for your feed-back. The code was re-edited. I am manually allocating a value to dir1array(ctr1) = file1.Name. This is done because the dir1array(ctr1) variable does not seem to take on the values of files in the dir1 folder.

Comment: You don't need to use Array's if you replace the "For Each file2 In dir2.Files" with something like "If fso.FileExists("c:\Tempo\" & file1.Name) Then" which will check the second folder for the file. From your code, you ignore if no matching file names, so this would work. Of course if you have other code that used the array... you need to keep your original.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Instead of opening a specific file i used Open "C:\Temp\" & File1.Name which enabled me to loop through the directory in both places where I had an arrays and it works.

Comment: I don't see an error trap in your code, so what happens if you don't have the matching file name in folder2?

Comment: The following code should be added: If file1.Name <> file2.Namel Then Exit Sub, Endif. What happens eventually is that a list of the different files are going to be written in a .txt file; and the similar/identical files are going to be written in another .txt file.

Comment: Unless there is some need to save the names in an Array, you may want to consider another approach. When I run your code on my 'Temp' folder, it bombs because the Array isn't large enough. I admit I don't know your environment, but somewhere in the future, the Array method may encounter an error. In a few minutes I will post what I think is an alternative method so you can see if it suits your needs.

Comment: Agreed, I am no longer using the array for this code. Instead I am using file1 and file2 that respectively point to Dir1 and Dir2 Hence, there won't be size limitations. But I am still curious to see your alternative method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  +1 for the question because this user has been responsive, flexible, humble, grateful and teachable.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a variation of your code, but does not use arrays.

```
Option Explicit

Sub findMatchFilenames()
Dim lLen1       As Long
Dim lLen2       As Long

Dim oFSO        As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim dir1        As Folder
Dim dir2        As Folder
Dim oFile1      As File
Dim oFile2      As File
Dim strFolder1  As String
Dim strFolder2  As String

    Close #1    ' I always close first when testing (in case I don't get to normal close)
    Close #2
    Open "C:\Temp\" & Format(Now(), "_SAME_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm") & ".txt" For Output As #1
    Open "C:\Temp\" & Format(Now(), "_Different_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm") & ".txt" For Output As #2

    Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject
    strFolder1 = "c:\Temp\"
    strFolder2 = "c:\Tempo\"

    Set dir1 = oFSO.GetFolder(strFolder1)
    Set dir2 = oFSO.GetFolder(strFolder2)

    For Each oFile1 In dir1.Files
        If oFSO.FileExists(strFolder2 & oFile1.Name) Then        ' If it matches same name
            Set oFile2 = oFSO.GetFile(strFolder2 & oFile1.Name)
            If oFile1.Size = oFile2.Size Then
                Print #1, oFile1.Name & vbTab & "File found in both folders; Size is the same;"
                Debug.Print oFile1.Name & vbTab & "File found in both folders; Size is the same;"
            Else
                Print #1, oFile1.Name & vbTab & "Found in both folders; Size is DIFFERENT; " & oFile1.Size & " vs: " & oFile2.Size
                Debug.Print oFile1.Name & vbTab & "Found in both folders; Size is DIFFERENT; " & oFile1.Size & " vs: " & oFile2.Size
            End If
        Else                ' Same file not found.
            Debug.Print "File not present in 2nd folder: " & oFile1.Name
            Print #1, oFile1.Name & vbTab & "File NOT found in second folder;"
        End If

    Next oFile1
    Set oFile1 = Nothing
    Set oFile2 = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing

    Close #1
    Close #2

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am looking at the result of your code and it looks good. There is one thing I have a bit of trouble with and it is the "size" attribute/function in oFile1.Size. For example, it gives a different size for a file that has the same size (i.e. the KB involved but also the number of characters in this file).

Comment: Are you sure the files are NOT different in size? The 'FileSize' is returned in bytes, so if you happen to look at a files properties in Windows Explorer, it can be expressed in KB or MB - which is a rounded number.  I would find a good file compare utility (i.e. WinDiff, VBinDiff, etc.) and run that against the two files. Please let me know the result as it would be highly unusual for the file size reporting to be incorrect..

Comment: About the file size, the problem is with the FileLen(file1) as it is supposed to give me a value and that value differs from one same size file to another. I am comparing two files that have the same number of characters and spaces between them. I'd have to try using the .Size function to give me a value and compare.

Comment: I just used the 'FileLen' with my code: 'lLen1 = FileLen(strFolder1 & oFile1.Name' and the returned value is identical to 'oFile1.Size' If you rather use 'FileLen', just change the code, but the result is the same.